# Why is my calculation returning "Infinity"?

Tags: java, math, methods

My program is supposed to calculate the BMI of a patient (with the method BMI()) but no matter what values I enter, it returns "Infinity". Based on my research, Infinity is returned when a value is divided by 0 but my program makes sure that values of 0 are not allowed. Can somebody please identify my logical error?

```
import java.util.*;
public class PDProjectOne {
    private static double weight, age, biximent, genFactor, bmi;
    private static String gender;
    
    public static double genderFactor(){
        if(gender.equals("R") || (gender.equals("r"))){
            genFactor = 8.46;
        }
        if(gender.equals("S") || (gender.equals("s"))){
            genFactor = 4.23;
        }
        if(gender.equals("T") || (gender.equals("t"))){
            genFactor = 6.35;
        }
        return genFactor;
    }
    
    public static double BMI(){
        bmi = 2.56 * age + ((biximent * 467)/(weight * genFactor));
        return bmi;
    }
    
    public static void report(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean good = false;
        do{
           System.out.print("Weight in kilograms:  ");
           weight = sc.nextDouble(); 
           if (weight <= 28){
               System.out.println("!! You must only enter a number greater than 28 kilograms. Try again. !!");
           }
           else{
            good = true;
        }
        } while (!good);
        
        good = false;
        do{
            System.out.print("Age in solar cycles:  ");
            age = sc.nextDouble();
            if (age >= 16 && age <= 96){
                good = true;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("!! You must only enter an age between 16 and 96 solar cycles. Try again. !!");
            }
        } while (!good);
        
        good = false;
        do{
            System.out.print("Gender identification:  ");
            gender = sc.next();
            if (gender.equals("R") || gender.equals("r") || gender.equals("S") || gender.equals("s") || 
                    gender.equals("T") || gender.equals("t")){
                good = true;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("!! You must only enter 'R','S',or 'T' as gender identifications. Try again. !!");
            }
        } while (!good);
        
        good = false;
        do{
            System.out.print("Biximent level:  ");
            biximent = sc.nextDouble();
            if (biximent >= 30){
                good = true;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("!! You must only enter a biximent level of at least 30. Try again. !!");
            }
        } while (!good);
        
        System.out.println("\nSUMMARY OF ANALYSIS:\n"
                + "For a citizen of gender type " + gender + ", who is " + age + " cycles old and weighs " + weight + " kilograms with"
                        + " a reported Biximent Level of " + biximent + ", the Biximent Metabolic Index (BMI) is " + BMI());
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If you don't call `genderFactor()`, `weight * genFactor` will be 0.

Comment: @shmosel I now see that this is my error. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. For the future, I'd suggest learning how to debug. This is exactly the type of problem that can be solved by stepping through the code.